# Is there a way to combine all of an applications updates and fixes with the original installation disc onto a new installation CD?

Tags: windows-xp

I am basically asking how to slipstream an application, I suppose.  Please note that I do not want to combine these applications into a slipstreamed OS, but keep them separate on their own installation CDs--just like they came out of the box, only updated!  Any help would be appreciated.  Im asking specifically for programs I run on XP PRO.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a program called [WinInstall](http://www.scalable.com/wininstall).

It builds differential-based installation images.

Comment: OK.  I checked out Wininstall, that isn't what I'm looking for.  It cost $1674.00!  I'm a home office user and only need to do this with a few programs.  Any ideas, anyone?  Thanks.

Comment: Ahh boo, there used to be a lite version that was only around $100. Sorry man -- thats the only program I know that easily packages things.

Answer (score 0):

as long as you have a decent level of computer knowledge and can follow instructions, you can follow the directions on [Paul Thurrott's winsupersite](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/product-review/slipstreaming-windows-xp-with-service-pack-2-sp2.aspx).  I've used it to create a number of slipstreamed win xp install discs.

Note: just substitute Service Pack 3 for SP2 in his article